# How to create react router transition like carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

I would like to animate my react router like "carousel".

I have A, B, C, D pages.

From move A to B I would like to animate from right to left.
From move B to A I would like to animate from LEFT to RIGH.

I found some example to make some "fade" animation, but nothing about "carousel" animation.

Do you have any tips, or idea how to make it with css, etc?

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel? It requires a bit of math, but is a pure css-based solution that can be made more flexible and powerful with some js.

Comment: Yes, something like this.

Comment: Hi! would this example work? https://pedrobern.github.io/react-tiger-transition/demo/carousel (I'm the package owner)

Answer (score 0):

So basically, one way to do it is based on the link in  the comment, just simplified and adapted to react. The trick is to make React Router work with the carousel.
For the router part, you will have something like this:

```
<Route path="/:page"
       render={
         props => <Layout selectedPage={props.location.state.selectedPage}/>
       }
/>
```

Then you have navigation:

```
<nav>
  <ul className="navigation">
    <li>
      <Link to={{pathname: '/mypage', state: {selectedPage: 0}}}>
        My page
      </Link>
    </li>
    // additional links omitted for brevity
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the main layout component:

```
const Layout = props => {

  const [radius, setRadius] = useState(0);
  const [theta, setTheta] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
      const cells = carousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel__cell');
      const cellWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
      const cellCount = cells.length;
      setTheta(360/cellCount);
      setRadius(Math.round((cellWidth / 2) / Math.tan(Math.PI / cellCount)));
      carousel.style.transform = 'translateZ(' + -radius + 'px)';
      for (let i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
        const cell = cells[i];
        cell.style.opacity = 1;
        const cellAngle = theta * i;
        cell.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + cellAngle + 'deg) translateZ(' + radius + 'px)';
      }
    }, [radius, theta]
  );

  useEffect(() => props.selectedPage !== undefined && rotateTo(props.selectedPage), [props.selectedPage]);

  const rotateTo = n => {
    const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    const angle = theta * n * -1;
    carousel.style.transform = 'translateZ(' + -radius + 'px) rotateY(' + angle + 'deg)';
  };

  return (
    <div className="scene">
      <div className="carousel">
        <div className="carousel__cell">1</div>
        <div className="carousel__cell">2</div>
        <div className="carousel__cell">3</div>
        <div className="carousel__cell">4</div>
        <div className="carousel__cell">5</div>
        <div className="carousel__cell">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

With the necessary css:

```
.scene {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 3em);
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(-288px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.carousel__cell {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 116px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

So basically, this is a bit simplified related to the example from the link, with no vertical rotation option, and no dynamic adding of cells (though it will calculate the appropriate values based on the number of .carousel__cell divs) and shoehorned to work with react-router. Not ideal, but it works.

You can see a full example at https://github.com/luinnarn/carousel-demo.